# Ergodic measures for the circle-doubling map are dense in the space of invariant measures

Tags: ergodic-theory

For the circle-doubling map $T:[0,1]\to [0,1]$, $x\mapsto 2x \mod(1)$. I want to show the ergodic probability measures are dense in the space of invariant probability measures.

My attempt: I know the Lebesgue measure $m$ is ergodic. Using binary expansion, the measure-preserving system $(T,m)$ is isomorphic to the Bernoulli shift $(1/2, 1/2)$. Using the same idea, for any $p\in (0,1)$, we can put the product measure of $(p,1-p)$ on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N_0}$, then pull it back to $[0,1]$ to get ergodic measures. But I am not sure how to prove the density.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/23443/66883 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/85984/66883.

Comment: Here is a suggestion. Given an invariant measure for the one sided shift $\mu = t \mu_1 + (1-t) \mu_2$, where $\mu_i$ is ergodic (I=1,2), can you prove that $\mu$ can be approximated by periodic measures (a measure supported on a periodic orbit with weight evenly distributed)? Once you do this, then you can take any invariant measure for the shift, approximate it by a convex combination of a finite number of ergodic measures (from ergodic decomposition) then approximate this convex combination by a periodic measure (which is ergodic).